# How to CONFIGURE WordPress on Synology NAS so that website is visible to the outside world

Tags: wordpress, web, public, configure, synology

This should be easy step, but there is no guidance, and my installation is turning into a week-long nightmare.

How do i configure Wordpress on NAS so that the website I create is visible on public internet through my domain mysite.com?
At the moment, I can only access my website through http://192.168.1.169/wordpress/
This is pointless, since I won't be able to invite public into my house, just too see my website. So there has to be a better way....

- ports 80/5000 on my router are enabled via Synology's EZ-internet app
- WebStation has virtualhost defined that points to my mysite.com at no-ip.com
- At no-ip. I defined as target MY IP, which I obtained by Googling "what's my public IP" from within my home network.
- when i enter mysite.com in browser, I am prompted to login to my ROUTER?!?!?! Why? I should be seeing my website developed on my Synology NAS, and I am not!

I cannot believe there are no user guides for this! And I cannot believe that noone knows how to do this!
No Youtube videos, no forums, no answers???

Extremely frustrated....

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have figured out the route just fine. If you're seeing the loginpage for your router, then two things may be happening:

1. Did you use http or httpS for your website address? The latter uses port 443 by default. I don't think you did, but I'll had to ask.
2. The router is currently configured to handle port 80 traffic for its logon page (which is scary in its own right; a router login page should not be accessible from internet). In this case the router should be configured to forward port 80 to port 80 on your Synology. Apparently EZ Internet did not do a good job configuring the port forwards for you, or the router is overriding these settings.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to log into your router and find your wan ip.  Then you substitute that into your address supplied above.  192.168.1.169 is an internal ip for your network.

This will only work though if you have set up port forwarding on your router to your NAS.

And port forwarding only works if you have assigned a static ip to your NAS using DHCP and your NAS mac address.

Also worth investigating is if your router provides a DMZ (de militarized zone).  Putting your NAS in the DMZ can increase security for the rest of your network that you want to keep hidden.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but maybe this still can help others.

- step 1: Set your port forwarding right (like the above suggestions). Port 80 and 443 should be open on your router and forwarded to your (fixed) internal IP address of your NAS.
- step 2: check with https://canyouseeme.org/ or a similar site if the ports are "really open". (was not the case for me when I checked)
- step 3: enable webstation and check if you can access the web landing page of your Synology by entering your DNS (from outside your LAN)

if all this works there is an important

- step 4: go to your Wordpress dashboard->settings->general

Adapt the site URL to use the DNS you have provided with "/wordpress" or another sub- domain.

Now you should be able to access it from outside

good luck